# Using blocktrans for translation

Tags: django

I am using the following blocktrans:

```
{% blocktrans with item|gender_text as gendertext %}
    This is {{gendertext}} item
{% endblocktrans %}
```

In my .po file I have

```
msgid "This is %(gendertext)s item"
msgstr "Some translation ... %(gendertext)s"
```

For any language other than english, I would not like to use the `gendertext` variable. So I would want to have

```
msgstr "Some translation ..."
```

However, when I take off the `%(gendertext)s` from from `msgstr`, django_admin shouts (when compiling the messages):

```
'msgstr' is not a valid Python format string, unlike 'msgid'. Reason: The string ends in the middle of a directive.
msgfmt: found 1 fatal error
```

Any workarounds for this case?

Meir

Comment: Put a condition in your template is not good for you?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, Django is right to give that error beacsue, your key should be there for all languages.For example, there is no such case : in English I have a key `gendertext` but in Turkish I don't need that key.

One easy solution is keep that key in both languages but keep it empty if you don't want to render.

Other than your question, I strongly recommend you to use `rosetta` application, http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/ for translation processes.